# How to put arch independent files into separated .deb package?

Tags: compiling, deb

When you build a deb how do you make it so arch independent data such as plugin files to be packaged into a separated .deb?

Answer (score 1):

I did this yesterday for the [Inkscape PPA](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev/inkscape/debian-packaging/files).  It's the first multiple-binary package I've written so I'm not 100% sure I've done things correctly, but basically there are two steps...

1. Add an arch-independent binary (whatever-plugins) package description into your debian/control file
2. Update the dependencies in your debian/control file so that your new whatever-plugins package is recommended/suggested by anything that needs it
3. Replace your debian/install file with separate debian/whatever.install and debian/whatever-plugins.install files, specifying which files should be part of each package.

There is also some fairly sparse documentation available in [the Debian developers' reference](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/best-pkging-practices.html#multiple-binary) and [maintainer's guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#install).  Would love to know if anyone else has found detailed documentation.